# Inequality in Probability

Tags: probability, random-variables, law-of-large-numbers

I'm not really convinced with a proof, made by my teacher, of the following inequality (which is then used to proof the Law of Large Numbers with hypotheses of i.i.d random variables and existance of $E[|X|]$):

> Let $X$ be a random variable, then: 
>   $\sum^{+\infty}_{n=1} \frac{1}{n^2} E[X^2.I_{\{|X|<n\}}] \leq 2E[|X|]$

The proof is quite simple, but I can't find the reason of a switch of two sums:

$$\begin{align}
\sum^{+\infty}_{n=1} \frac{1}{n^2} E[X^2.I_{\{|X|<n\}}] &= \sum^{+\infty}_{n=1} \sum_{k \leq n} \frac{1}{n^2} E[X^2.I_{ \{k-1 \leq|X|<k\}}]\\
&\leq \sum^{+\infty}_{k=1}E[X^2.I_{ \{k-1 \leq|X|<k\}}] \sum^{+\infty}_{n=1} \frac{1}{n^2}\\
&\leq 2 \sum^{+\infty}_{k=1} \frac{1}{k}E[X^2.I_{ \{k-1 \leq|X|<k\}}]\\
&\leq \sum^{+\infty}_{k=1} E[|X|.I_{\{k-1\leq|X|<k\}}]\\
&=2E[|X|] 
\end{align}
$$

I can't really understand why, passing from the second to the third term, he switched the sums: some hypoteses of absolute convergence should be needed, but  don't find them. Thanks to everybody.

Comment: If all terms have the same sign then sums can always be interchanged (at worst both orders give an infinite result).

Comment: Ok, I'm stupid. Thank you very much!